# Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 Basic Program Error

Tags: c++

I'm making this program that takes my family member's names and gives out their horoscope.  And I'm getting some errors which bugs me. The random names are just for "privacy". And yes I'm just a starter and  im working with basic arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string name;
    string hs[4];
    hs[0] = "Aquarius";
    hs[1] = "Cancer";
    hs[2] = "Leo";  
    hs[3] = "Taurus";  
    cin >> name;
    if name = "Harp"
    {
    cout << hs[0] << endl;
}
if name = "Herp"
{
        cout << hs[1] << endl;
        }
        if name = "Derp"
        {
        cout << hs[2] << endl;
        }
               if name = "Darp"
        {
                cout << hs[3] << endl;       
                }


    cout << "Press Enter To Exit This Program.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this:
 expected `(' before "name"
Any help would be nice.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.7.1 x64 or 4.7.1, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: Ok, I'll do so later.

Comment: Did you make it? Since your name is orwell and its called orwell dev cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out proper `if` syntax. - missing `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (name == "Harp")
```

Pay attention to the `(` and `)`, they are not optional. Also use `==` (not `=`, it assing the value in the right side to the left, here name will have change the contenct to "Harp", and then convert it to bool, ...)

Answer (score 0):

the corrected program is this. Note the proper syntax of if statement

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string name;
    string hs[4];
    hs[0] = "Aquarius";
    hs[1] = "Cancer";
    hs[2] = "Leo";  
    hs[3] = "Taurus";  
    cin >> name;
    if (name == "Harp")
    {
    cout << hs[0] << endl;
}
if (name == "Herp")
{
        cout << hs[1] << endl;
        }
        if (name == "Derp")
        {
        cout << hs[2] << endl;
        }
               if (name == "Darp")
        {
                cout << hs[3] << endl;       
                }


    cout << "Press Enter To Exit This Program.";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you even fixed it for me! 4char

Comment: One thing though, it said "stdafx.h" was no such file or directory. Is stdafx.h required for this program to work?